# how to pass references to javascript links in main page in gwt main page

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

i am working on a GWT project , and i want to use another javascript project that written  in javascript . at this moment i refer to its javascript libs in this maner :

```
 <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://192.168.10.100:7001/mapviewer/fsmc/jslib/oraclemaps.js"></script>
```

for some reason i want to use a dynamic Ip (i do not hard code it in my main page);

i copied javascript in my project but as you see it is deployed on weblogic app server and it does not work correct when i copy that javascript in my project;

how can i do this.
please help me

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As say in other answer, use the ScriptInjector.
But add the script to the top windows and use a callback to wait the loading of the script before call the JSNI :

```
public void callMapViewer(String ip) {
    ScriptInjector.fromUrl("http//"+ip+"/mapviewer/fsmc/jslib/oraclemaps.js‌​").setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW).setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            callJSNI();
        }
    });
}

public native void callJSNI() /*-{
    $wnd.fonctionJS();
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the source dynamically, you can use a GWT [ScriptInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html).

Comment: i added this line of code just before of the place that call jsni code : ScriptInjector.fromUrl("//192.168.10.100:7001/mapviewer/fsmc/jslib/oraclemaps.js");i can see javascript in firebug but it stiil raise this exception :...createPluginMap is not defined

Comment: Read about GWT JSNI and how to reference native code  from GWT code.